# Adding a class to existing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-back bi bi-bicycle">
```

CSS:

```
.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(10px);
}
.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(0);
}
```

Above are my existing code structure; am trying to add the ‘flipped’ class into the ‘card-back’ class ON CLICK in order to flip my card - desired output:
`<div class="card-back flipped bi bi-bicycle">`

Wrote the following function but it didn’t work:

```
const flipCard = () => {
  $(“.card-back”).on(“click”, (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).classList.add(“flipped”);
  });
};
flipCard();
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `“` and `”` are invalid symbols here; use `"` instead. _“but it couldn’t work”_ isn’t a meaningful problem description. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal?

Comment: `$(event.currentTarget).classList` classList is not a property of a jquery object.   Just use `event.currentTarget.classList` - or use jquery method `$(event.currentTarget).addClass("flipped")`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "div.card-back" , function() {
    $(this).addClass("flipped");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add the class as you wanted:

```
const flipCard = () => {
  console.log("click")
  $('.card').on('click', (event) => {
    $('.card-back').toggleClass('flipped');
    console.log("click")
  });
};
flipCard();
```